# change crs mode with addEventListener in leafletjs

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to get a custom map with Django-leaflet in the admin page. When I edit the source code I get it working with a modification of this code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    minZoom: -2
});
var bounds = [[0,0], [2781,3673]];
var image = L.imageOverlay('/static/plattegrond.jpg', bounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

However when I want to leave the django-leaflet module in tact I have to change the CRS mode with an addEventListener:

```
  window.addEventListener("map:init", function (event) {
    var map = event.detail.map; // Get reference to map
    var bounds = [[0,0], [2781,3673]];
    var image = L.imageOverlay('/static/plattegrond.jpg', bounds).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

I have no idea how to change the CRS mode to CRS.Simple this way. Now I get a stretched image,

Edit:
Thanks to a comment from peeebeee I found a way to change to crs.simple. Unfortunately django-leaflet doesn't allow to set negative zoom, so thats my next challenge:

```
  window.addEventListener("map:init", function (event) {
    var map = event.detail.map; // Get reference to map
     map.options.crs = L.CRS.Simple;
    var bounds = [[0,0], [2781,3673]];
    var image = L.imageOverlay('/static/plattegrond.jpg', bounds).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

In settings.py I set these options:

```
LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
    'TILES': [],
    'LAYERS':[],
    'SPATIAL_EXTENT': (0, 0, 2781,3673)
}
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Longer answer: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2553

Comment: @peeebeee Thanks to your link I found a way to change to crs.simple. See question if you are interested. Thanks!